# How to sum the value for certain condition in R?

Tags: r, list, sum, min

I have a lot of lists and I want to sum the min value of each list which the min value is less than 3. 
For instants,

```
a <- c(3,4,1,5,6)
b <- c(2,1,1,0,5)
c <- c(6,7,5,4,4)
list1 <- list(a,b,c)
minlist1 <- lapply(list1, min)
sum(unlist(minlist1 <=1))
> minlist1
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 4
> sum(unlist(minlist1 <=3))
[1] 2
#but according to the minlist1 the value should be sum up is 1 and 0
#so the result should be 1 no 2.
```

But according to the minlist1 the value should be sum up is 1 and 0. So the result should be 1 no 2.
Please give me a hint how can I do that. Thank you

Comment: `minlist1 <=3` returns `FALSE/TRUE` coded as `0/1`. There are 2 `TRUE` values, the sum is 2.

Comment: Roman's way is recommended using `sapply` but to complete your attempt, you need to do `sum(unlist(minlist1[minlist1 <=3]))` if you are using `lapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. When you are checking for `minlist1 <= 3`, the returned result is TRUE, TRUE, FALSE. When you try to sum a logical vector, TRUE is coerced into 1 and FALSE into 0. You need to explicitly subset elements which pass your filter.

Try

```
minlist1 <- sapply(list1, min)
sum(minlist1[minlist1 <= 3])
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of showing you another way.

```
minlist1 <- unlist( sapply(list1, function(x){ res = min(x); if(res <=3) res else { NULL } }) )

sum(minlist1)

#[1] 1
```

Please note:

Here you are using a "trick" that `NULL` can't exist in a vector and therefore values > 3 are removed from you sum. Type `c(1,NULL,NULL,3)` into console.